# RegExp replace word not starting with certain symbols

Tags: regex

Can I do this?

```
...blah-blah...AA_word.......blah-blah...AB_word......word........Nword....
```

I need to replace only those occurences of word that don't start with "AB_" so it will look like this:

```
...blah-blah...AA_XXXX.......blah-blah...AB_word......XXXX........NXXXX....
```

Is this possible? I'm more or less familiar with regex but still unable to find out how to do it. Programming language doesn't matter - php, js or c#, whatever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for : `(?<!AB_)word`
and replace with: `XXXX`

A perl implementation:

```
my $str = "...blah-blah...AA_word.......blah-blah...AB_word......word........Nword....";
$str =~ s/(?<!AB_)word/XXXX/g;
say $str;
```

**Output:**

```
...blah-blah...AA_XXXX.......blah-blah...AB_word......XXXX........NXXXX....
```

With php:

```
$str = "...blah-blah...AA_word.......blah-blah...AB_word......word........Nword....";
$str = preg_replace('/(?<!AB_)word/', 'XXXX', $str);
echo "$str\n";
```

Comment: Never knew about this. For curious cats, this is called *Negative lookbehind assertion*. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In JS:

```
var s = "...blah-blah...AA_word.......blah-blah...AB_word......word........Nword...."

s.replace("AB_word", "????").replace(/word/g, "XXXX").replace("????", "AB_word")
// results in 
// ...blah-blah...AA_XXXX.......blah-blah...AB_word......XXXX........NXXXX....
```

HTH